# How to remove loops in my R code to speed-up the calculation of how many days of overlap inbetween each worker in a same location

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

#I would like to know how many days each worker has days in common with each other, in a same location (don't care of overlap when the location are differents).

```
library(dplyr)
```

#For exemple, a planning of 6 days :

```
Planning_days = 1:6
```

#For exemple, 5 workers in zoneA and 3 in zoneB, with their arrival and departure days :

```
Attendance = as.data.frame(rbind(
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Jean", arrival_day=1, departure_day=2),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Paul", arrival_day=4, departure_day=5),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Bob",  arrival_day=2, departure_day=3),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Will", arrival_day=2, departure_day=4),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Dan",  arrival_day=6, departure_day=6),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Max",  arrival_day=1, departure_day=1),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Leo",  arrival_day=2, departure_day=5),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Abel", arrival_day=3, departure_day=4)
))
```

#In my low-speed solution, I added to that dataframe all the days as following "column names",

#then I use 2 imbricated for loops like this :

```
Attendance_mtx <- Attendance[,c("location","worker")]
Attendance_mtx[, as.character(Planning_days)] <- F

for(i in 1:nrow(Attendance_mtx)) {
  Attendance_mtx[i, 2 + which(Planning_days >= Attendance[i,"arrival_day",drop=T] & Planning_days <= Attendance[i,"departure_day",drop=T])] <- T
}

Mtx_overlap <- Attendance[,c("location","worker")]
locations = unique(Attendance$location)

for(i in 1:length(locations)) {
  Attendance_mtx_tmp <- Attendance_mtx %>% filter(location == locations[i])
  for(j in 1:nrow(Attendance_mtx_tmp)) {
    for(k in 1:nrow(Attendance_mtx_tmp)) {
      if(j != k) {
        Overlap_length = length(which(Attendance_mtx_tmp[j, 3:ncol(Attendance_mtx_tmp)] & Attendance_mtx_tmp[k, 3:ncol(Attendance_mtx_tmp)]))
        if(Overlap_length > 0) {
          Mtx_overlap[Mtx_overlap$worker==Attendance_mtx_tmp[j,"worker",drop=T], Attendance_mtx_tmp[k,"worker",drop=T]] <- Overlap_length
          Mtx_overlap[Mtx_overlap$worker==Attendance_mtx_tmp[k,"worker",drop=T], Attendance_mtx_tmp[j,"worker",drop=T]] <- Overlap_length
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
res1 <- Mtx_overlap %>% mutate_at(vars(3:ncol(Mtx_overlap)), ~replace(., is.na(.), 0))
```

#I'd like to get those 2 kinds of following results (dataframe as res1/res1bis, list as res2) :

```
res1 = as.data.frame(rbind(
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Jean", Bob=1, Jean=0, Will=1, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Paul", Bob=0, Jean=0, Will=1, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Bob",  Bob=0, Jean=1, Will=2, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Will", Bob=2, Jean=1, Will=0, Paul=1, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Dan",  Bob=0, Jean=0, Will=0, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Max",  Bob=0, Jean=0, Will=0, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Leo",  Bob=0, Jean=0, Will=0, Paul=0, Abel=2, Leo=0),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Abel", Bob=0, Jean=0, Will=0, Paul=0, Abel=0, Leo=2)
))
```

#NB1: I don't care of the columns' order for res1)

#NB2: res1 column can include Dan and Max even if these whole 2 columns will be full of 0), like this (res1bis) :

```
res1bis = as.data.frame(rbind(
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Jean", Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=1, Will=1, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Paul", Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=1, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Bob",  Jean=1, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=2, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Will", Jean=1, Paul=1, Bob=2, Will=0, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneA", worker="Dan",  Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=0, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Max",  Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=0, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=0),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Leo",  Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=0, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=0, Abel=2),
  c(location="zoneB", worker="Abel", Jean=0, Paul=0, Bob=0, Will=0, Dan=0, Max=0, Leo=2, Abel=0)
))
```

```
res2 = list(
  "zoneA" = list(
    "Jean" = list(Bob=1, Will=1),
    "Paul" = list(Will=1),
    "Bob"  = list(Jean=1, Will=2),
    "Will" = list(Bob=2, Jean=1, Paul=1),
    "Dan"  = list()
  ),
  "zoneB" = list(
    "Max"  = list(),
    "Leo"  = list(Abel=2),
    "Abel" = list(Leo=2)
  )
)
```

#It takes 15 minutes for 20000 persons and 200 days.

#I'am not very familar with [s/t/l]apply functions, but I think it is possible to make this calculation faster with them.

#Any idea ?

Comment: Never use `as.data.frame(rbind(..))`, it is needless and corrupting the data (numbers to strings). Form it in almost any other way that preserves numbers as they should be. If you must use that "collection of vectors", then change `c(..)` to `list(..)`, and change `as.data.frame(rbind(` to `do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(`.

Comment: `mutate_at` has been superseded for over 2 years, switch to `across`.

Comment: What's the scale of the problem you want to solve? (eg roughly how many people per location?) That will help define what approaches will be most performant. If the workers are generally each in a low number of locations, you might be able to do a join of all observations per location, then filter for worker.x != worker.y and time overlap.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on the nature of the data (see comment by @Jon Spring), but right now your solution is O(n^2). Below should be closer to O(n).

Go through and enumerate who worked on each day at each location, then collect the list of workers for the groupings

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

attendanceByDay <- Attendance_mtx |> 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches('[[:digit:]]+'),
    names_to = "day",
    names_transform = as.integer,
    values_to = "present"
  ) |> 
  filter(present) |> 
  select(-present) 

workersEachDay <- attendanceByDay |> 
  group_by(location, day) |> 
  summarize(workersPresent = list(worker[day == cur_group()$day]), .groups = "drop")
```

Create a "matrix" or "scorecard" of how many times each worker worked with everyone else at a given location.

```
res1 <- bind_cols(
  expand_grid(location = locations, worker = workers),
  map_dfc(workers, \(x) tibble(!!x := 0))
)
```

Lastly, iterate through each location/day combo. Add plus one to the relevant rows in the "scorecard" as they all were present together.

```
for(i in seq(NROW(workersEachDay))){
  
  curRow <- slice(workersEachDay, i)
  curLoc <- curRow$location
  curDay <- curRow$day

  res1Rows <- res1$location == curLoc & res1$worker %in% curRow$workersPresent[[1]]
  res1Cols <- colnames(res1) %in% curRow$workersPresent[[1]]
  
  res1[res1Rows, res1Cols] <- res1[res1Rows, res1Cols] + 1
}

res1
#> # A tibble: 16 × 10
#>    location worker  Jean  Paul   Bob  Will   Dan   Max   Leo  Abel
#>    <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 zoneA    Jean       2     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
#>  2 zoneA    Paul       0     2     0     1     0     0     0     0
#>  3 zoneA    Bob        1     0     2     2     0     0     0     0
#>  4 zoneA    Will       1     1     2     3     0     0     0     0
#>  5 zoneA    Dan        0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
#>  6 zoneA    Max        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7 zoneA    Leo        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  8 zoneA    Abel       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  9 zoneB    Jean       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 10 zoneB    Paul       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 11 zoneB    Bob        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 12 zoneB    Will       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 13 zoneB    Dan        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 14 zoneB    Max        0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
#> 15 zoneB    Leo        0     0     0     0     0     0     4     2
#> 16 zoneB    Abel       0     0     0     0     0     0     2     2
```

Hopefully, you know how to reshape the data then into the format `res2`. If not that should be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have another answer using dplyr / tidyr. Starting with Attendance

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
# For exemple, a planning of 6 days :

Planning_days <-  1:6
# For exemple, 5 workers in zoneA and 3 in zoneB, with their arrival and departure days :

Attendance <- tibble::tribble(
    ~location, ~worker, ~arrival_day, ~departure_day,
    "zoneA",  "Jean",            1,              2,
    "zoneA",  "Paul",            4,              5,
    "zoneA",   "Bob",            2,              3,
    "zoneA",  "Will",            2,              4,
    "zoneA",   "Dan",            6,              6,
    "zoneB",   "Max",            1,              1,
    "zoneB",   "Leo",            2,              5,
    "zoneB",  "Abel",            3,              4
  ) 
# Make sure I give the results in the same order as you did.
order <- unique(Attendance$worker)

# Using seq function to enumerate all days.
days_present <- Attendance %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(ends_with("day"))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(span = consecutive_id(location, worker)) %>% 
  group_by(span, location, worker) %>% 
  reframe(
    days_present = seq(value[name == "arrival_day"], value[name == "departure_day"], by = 1)
  ) %>% 
  select(-span)

days_present
#> # A tibble: 17 × 3
#>    location worker days_present
#>    <chr>    <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 zoneA    Jean              1
#>  2 zoneA    Jean              2
#>  3 zoneA    Paul              4
#>  4 zoneA    Paul              5
#>  5 zoneA    Bob               2
#>  6 zoneA    Bob               3
#>  7 zoneA    Will              2
#>  8 zoneA    Will              3
#>  9 zoneA    Will              4
#> 10 zoneA    Dan               6
#> 11 zoneB    Max               1
#> 12 zoneB    Leo               2
#> 13 zoneB    Leo               3
#> 14 zoneB    Leo               4
#> 15 zoneB    Leo               5
#> 16 zoneB    Abel              3
#> 17 zoneB    Abel              4

combination_long <- days_present %>% 
  group_by(location, days_present) %>% 
  mutate(other_worker = list(worker)) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(other_worker) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(worker == other_worker, 0, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(other_worker, worker), \(x) factor(x, levels = order))) %>%
  # filter(worker != other_worker) %>%  # to get res1bis, uncomment here
  group_by(location, worker, other_worker) %>% 
  summarise(
    value = sum(value),
    .groups = "drop"
  )

combination_long
#> # A tibble: 18 × 4
#>    location worker other_worker value
#>    <chr>    <fct>  <fct>        <dbl>
#>  1 zoneA    Jean   Jean             0
#>  2 zoneA    Jean   Bob              1
#>  3 zoneA    Jean   Will             1
#>  4 zoneA    Paul   Paul             0
#>  5 zoneA    Paul   Will             1
#>  6 zoneA    Bob    Jean             1
#>  7 zoneA    Bob    Bob              0
#>  8 zoneA    Bob    Will             2
#>  9 zoneA    Will   Jean             1
#> 10 zoneA    Will   Paul             1
#> 11 zoneA    Will   Bob              2
#> 12 zoneA    Will   Will             0
#> 13 zoneA    Dan    Dan              0
#> 14 zoneB    Max    Max              0
#> 15 zoneB    Leo    Leo              0
#> 16 zoneB    Leo    Abel             2
#> 17 zoneB    Abel   Leo              2
#> 18 zoneB    Abel   Abel             0

combination_long %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(location, worker),
    names_from = other_worker,
    values_fill = 0,
     names_sort = TRUE
  )
```

### res1

```r
#> # A tibble: 8 × 10
#>   location worker  Jean  Paul   Bob  Will   Dan   Max   Leo  Abel
#>   <chr>    <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 zoneA    Jean       0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 2 zoneA    Paul       0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
#> 3 zoneA    Bob        1     0     0     2     0     0     0     0
#> 4 zoneA    Will       1     1     2     0     0     0     0     0
#> 5 zoneA    Dan        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 6 zoneB    Max        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 7 zoneB    Leo        0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2
#> 8 zoneB    Abel       0     0     0     0     0     0     2     0
```

My answer to res2 is partial. I think it is not very efficient, and doesn't really have what you need.

```r
interim <- combination_long %>% 
  # filter(worker != other_worker) %>% 
  nest(.by = c(location, worker)) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, \(x) tibble::deframe(x))) %>% 
  nest(.by = c(location)) %>% 
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, \(x) set_names(x[[2]], x[[1]]))) 
# res2 
set_names(interim$data, interim$location)
#> $zoneA
#> $zoneA$Jean
#> Jean  Bob Will 
#>    0    1    1 
#> 
#> $zoneA$Paul
#> Paul Will 
#>    0    1 
#> 
#> $zoneA$Bob
#> Jean  Bob Will 
#>    1    0    2 
#> 
#> $zoneA$Will
#> Jean Paul  Bob Will 
#>    1    1    2    0 
#> 
#> $zoneA$Dan
#> Dan 
#>   0 
#> 
#> 
#> $zoneB
#> $zoneB$Max
#> Max 
#>   0 
#> 
#> $zoneB$Leo
#>  Leo Abel 
#>    0    2 
#> 
#> $zoneB$Abel
#>  Leo Abel 
#>    2    0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note: some lines could be removed if the order is not important to you.